# Java: Parsing Date as String which may or may not contain timezone info

Tags: java, date, jodatime

Currently I am using below date parser to parse the date which is passed as `String`:

```
public static final DateTimeParser FRACTION_PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
.appendLiteral('.').appendFractionOfSecond(0, 3).toParser();

public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
.appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
.appendOptional(FRACTION_PARSER).appendLiteral('Z')
.toFormatter();
```

And I have below conditions to parse:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(DATE_FORMATTER.parseDateTime("2016-01-13T13:38:19.679Z"));
    System.out.println(DATE_FORMATTER.parseDateTime("2016-01-13T13:38:19.67Z"));
    System.out.println(DATE_FORMATTER.parseDateTime("2016-01-13T13:38:19.6Z"));
    System.out.println(DATE_FORMATTER.parseDateTime("2016-01-13T13:38:19Z"));
    System.out.println(DATE_FORMATTER.parseDateTime("2016-01-15T16:58:57.649-05:00"));
}
```

It parses the first four cases correctly but is failing for the last one with below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2016-01-15T16:58:57.649-05:00" is malformed at "-05:00"

I understand its failinf as I appended literal `Z` to the format. But I was expecting it to work as a timeZone parser!

Is there any simple way to use the same parser with optional parameter for all the above formats? or do I need to use different formats depending on the string that I get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.appendLiteral('Z')` means that you expect the letter 'Z' here, nothing else.

Use `appendTimeZoneOffset(String zeroOffsetText, boolean showSeparators, int minFields, int maxFields)` instead to expect the time zone offset.

For example: 
`.appendTimeZoneOffset("Z", true, 2, 2)` means time zone offset with hours and minutes or 'Z' for "Zulu" (UTC).

Comment: Is it optional? or it will be required everytime to have some timezone in the String?

Comment: It is mandatory. If you want to make it optional, wrap it in another parser and use appendOptional(parser).